# Orbit an element around another in the z axis (z index)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, plugins

I saw a plugin a while ago but can not find it. It orbits an element by starting it behind another element, slides it to the right, switches the z-index to be greater than the element and slides it to the left (making it biggest in the middle), then switches z-index to be lower, and slides it behind the element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Search Term: "jquery zindex orbit element"

4th Result: http://css-tricks.com/examples/Circulate/

Comment: Thank you so much. I was only getting the orbit image slideshow.